# Battery remaining time is not shown in KDE after upgrade to Kubuntu 23.10

Tags: linux, laptop, battery, kde, kubuntu

I upgraded my computer from Kubuntu 23.04 to 23.10 and now it refuses to show me the estimated battery time anymore ([not showing remaining time of battery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RE9pk.png), sorry about the Slovenian language on the OS).

I have (neofetch output):

```
aleks@Victus 
------------ 
OS: Kubuntu 23.10 x86_64 
Host: Victus by HP Gaming Laptop 15-fa0044nm
Kernel: 6.5.5-060505-generic 
Uptime: 2 hours, 58 mins 
Packages: 3621 (dpkg), 24 (flatpak), 14 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.2.15 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: Plasma 5.27.8 
WM: KWin 
Theme: [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3] 
Icons: kora-light [Plasma], kora-light [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: konsole 
CPU: 12th Gen Intel i7-12700H (20) @ 4.600GHz 
GPU: Intel Alder Lake-P 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile 
Memory: 5345MiB / 15644MiB
```